# Errno 61 Connection refused & Errno 54 Connection reset by peer on Echo Server

Tags: python

I'm looking for some help!!!!! I'm some what new to Python so please beare with me. I'm trying to create an Echo Server with to Clients in Side it. One checking a MySQL and the other checking a port on the server. The Clients are sending the data to the Echo Server and the server send the data back out to all connected Clients.

It runs for about 2 hours then I get errors like:

```
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
[Errno 61] Connection refused
```

System:
MAC OS X Lion 10.7.3
Memory: 5GB
Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

Is this the best way to do this?
What is the best way? Please Help.

Here is my code:

```
class Database(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Database, self).__init__()
        self.is_stop = Event()
        self.is_stop.clear()
        _cfg          = cfg.Config().DataBase()
        self.dbHost   = _cfg.dbHost
        self.dbUser   = _cfg.dbUser
        self.dbPass   = _cfg.dbPass
        self.dbName   = _cfg.dbName
        self.dbPort   = _cfg.dbPort

    def run(self):
        print "Database pid %s" % self.pid

        while not self.is_stop.is_set():
            rows = self.getData()
            for row in rows:
                vTable  = str(row[0])
                vType   = str(row[1])
                vStatus = str(row[2])

                sData   = 'table:'+vTable+',action:'+vType+',data: '

                try :
                    time.sleep(2)
                    conn = self.createSocket()
                    conn.sendall(sData+"\0")
                    self.delPollData(vTable,vType,vStatus)

                    if socket.timeout:
                        #log.debug("Database Socket Timedout")
                        continue
                    else:
                        data = conn.recv(1024)
                    continue

                    conn.close()
                    conn = None
                    time.sleep(2)
                except:
                    time.sleep(2)
                    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                    print "Database Error: %s" %e
                    log.debug("Database Error: %s" %e)
                    conn = self.createSocket()
                    conn.sendall(sData+"\0")

                    if socket.timeout:
                        log.debug("Database Socket Except Timedout")
                        continue
                    else:
                        data = conn.recv(1024)
                    continue

                    conn.close()
                    conn = None
                    time.sleep(2)

            time.sleep(1)

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.dbHost,port=self.dbPort,user=self.dbUser,passwd=self.dbPass,db=self.dbName)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def commit(self):
        self.connection.commit()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    def getData(self):
        sqlcmd = """SELECT DISTINCT NAME, TYPE, STATUS FROM SERVER_AUDIT"""
        try:
            self.connect()
            self.cursor.execute (sqlcmd)
            result =  self.cursor.fetchall()
            self.disconnect()
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[1]
            log.error("getData %s"%e, sys, traceback)
            sys.exit(e)
        return result

     def createSocket(self) :
        _cfgServer = cfg.Config().EchoServer()
        EchoHost  = _cfgServer.EchoServerHost
        EchoPort = int(float(str(_cfgServer.EchoServerPorts)))

        conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        conn.settimeout(60.0)
        conn.connect((EchoHost, EchoPort))
        return conn

class pChecker(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pChecker, self).__init__()
        self.is_stop = Event()
        self.is_stop.clear()

    def check_server(self, address, port):
        # Create a TCP socket
        s = socket.socket()
        try:
            s.connect((address, port))
            s.close()
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def createSocket(self) :
        _cfgServer = cfg.Config().EchoServer()
        EchoHost  = _cfgServer.EchoServerHost
        EchoPort = int(float(str(_cfgServer.EchoServerPorts)))

        conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        conn.settimeout(60)
        conn.connect((EchoHost, EchoPort))
        return conn

    def run(self):
        print "pChecker pid %s" % self.pid
        while not self.is_stop.is_set():
            modem1 = self.check_server('XX.X.X.XXX', XXX)

            modem  = ''

            if modem1 != True :
                modem = "modem1:connect,"
            else:
                modem = "modem1:disconnect,"

            try :
                time.sleep(2)
                conn = self.createSocket()
                conn.sendall("[modem]"+modem[:-1]+"\0")
                #data = conn.recv(1024)

                if socket.timeout:
                    #log.debug("pChecker Socket Timedout")
                    continue
                else:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                continue

                conn.close()
                conn = None
                time.sleep(2)
            except:
                time.sleep(2)
                e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                log.error("pChecker %s"%e, sys, traceback)
                conn = self.createSocket()
                conn.sendall("[modem]"+modem[:-1]+"\0")
                #data = conn.recv(1024)

                if socket.timeout:
                    log.debug("pChecker Socket Timedout")
                    continue
                else:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                continue

                #print data
                conn.close()
                conn = None
                time.sleep(2)


class Server(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.is_stop = Event()
        self.is_stop.clear()

    def run(self):
        print "Server pid %s" % self.pid

        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.server.bind((EchoHost,EchoPort))
        self.server.listen(64)
        self.input = [self.server]
        try:
            while not self.is_stop.is_set():

                inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(self.input,[],[])

                for s in inputready:

                    if s == self.server:
                        # handle the server socket
                        client, address = self.server.accept()
                        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (address[0],address[1])
                        ClientIP = str(address[0])
                        self.input.append(client)

                    elif s == sys.stdin:
                        # handle standard input
                        junk = sys.stdin.readline()
                        running = 0

                    else:
                        # handle all other sockets
                        try:
                            data = s.recv(1024)
                            #print "Send Data %s" %data
                        except IOError as e:
                            f = sys.exc_info()[1]
                            log.error("Server Error: %s" %f, sys, traceback)
                            if e.args[1].args[0].errno != errno.ECONNERSET:
                                raise

                        tempConn = self.input[1:len(self.input)]

                        if data:
                                for i in tempConn:
                                        i.send(data)
                                        if ClientIP != '10.0.1.2':
                                            log.info('See to Client: %s data: %s'%ClientIP,data)

                        else:
                            s.close()
                            self.input.remove(s)
            print "Server: exiting"
            log.info("Server: exiting")
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[1]
            log.error("Server Error: %s" %e, sys, traceback)
```

Comment: This is way too complex for an echo server. Have a look at the [Python  documentation for a good example](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example). In general, at stackoverflow, we solve problems with limited excerpts of code (if at all possible [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/)). If you have significantly more than 20 lines, you're looking for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: phihag Thanks for your reply I have looked at these doc and it does not show how to send to all connected Clients it only shows one on one connections.